# Javascript check if unix timestamp > 24hours from now?

Tags: javascript, timestamp

Is there any easy way to check if a unix timestamp (ex: 1442957750) is a time which is > 24 hours from right now?  I'm having trouble with the conversion from linux timestamp to something JS can deal with

Thanks!

Comment: You can multiply Linux dates by 1000 and directly instantiate JavaScript dates from that.

Comment: `Math.round(Date.getTime()/1000)` results in a Unixtimestamp (of the local machine time). JS deals with miliseconds since 01.01.1970 not seconds

Comment: Keep in mind that 24 hours != one day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Unix-style timestamp can be used in JavaScript, but you need to convert it from seconds to milliseconds by multiplying by 1,000.

```
new Date(1442957750000) // Tue Sep 22 2015 16:35:50 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

24 hours is equal to 86,400,000 milliseconds.  You can do the math from there.  And do remember daylight savings time and what not.  Not all days are created equal.

```
(new Date(new Date() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) - new Date(1442957750 * 1000)) < 0
```

Answer (score 4):

I think it's solve your problem, just convert both time to JS.

```js
function convertUnixDate(date, multiplier = 1000){
 let isSecond = !(date > (Date.now() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) / 1000)

 return date
  ? isSecond
   ? new Date(date * multiplier)
   : new Date(date)
  : null
};

console.log(convertUnixDate(1522355774))
console.log(convertUnixDate(1522355774000))
console.log(convertUnixDate(null)) // Return the now() is an improvement.
```

[]'s

Answer (score 0):

`unix_timestamp > (Date.now() + 24*60*60*1000)/1000`

Have to convert the js time stamp to seconds from milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

To deal with things like daylight savings time, you can use the JavaScript Date API to make a date exactly one day ahead of the current time:

```
var oneDayFromNow = new Date();
oneDayFromNow.setDate(oneDayFromNow.getDate() + 1);
```

Then you can make a Date instance from the Linux timestamp value and check to see which is bigger:

```
var linuxDate = new Date(linuxTimestamp * 1000);
if (linuxDate >= oneDayFromNow) {
  // linux date is a day or more in the future
}
```

By letting the JavaScript runtime advance the date forward by one day, you let it use the code built into the runtime that understands local daylight savings time, etc.